# C++ Cygwin numeric constant build error in template

Tags: c++, templates, cygwin, constants, numeric

I have problem with latest cygwin(1.7.24 64bit, GCC 4.8.1-3 64bit) compiler in this template:

```
template <typename _T, int _N>
vector<_T> makeVector(const _T(&data)[_N]) {
    return vector<_T> (data, data + _N);
}
```

Compiler says:

```
error: expected '>' before numeric constant
```

But I am pretty sure it's valid code, because I build it in past on Windows with TDM-GCC and on school test Linux.

If you know how to solve this, please let me know,
Thanks.

Comment: Is this your code or code owned by the standard library? ... because it is **not** valid user code!

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's not valid library code either, unless some special compiler behavior is involved, since as a programmer, I have a right to do `#define data 42` before including any of the system headers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I was about to state the same but, actually, a user is **not** allowed to `#define data 42` before including any part of the standard C++ library, because `data` happens to be the name of a member of one of the standard C++ classes or class templates (e.g. `data` is a member of `std::basic_string` and `std::Vector`). That is, the library is actually allowed to use the identifier `data`! Well, not only allowed - it has to use it in some places.

Comment: @DietmarKühl This is a template from our university teacher and we have to implement CSearch class to search substrings in strings.

Complete code is here: http://pastebin.com/0i31p31C

I test it in Visual Studio and it works fine.

Comment: @CdTCzech: It seems you teacher is teaching you bad practices: names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter are always reserved for use by the standard C++ library.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Good point.  But the user could define `makeVector` (I think).  It's an interesting point, though.  As a user, I'd avoid any `#define` that weren't all caps, because of such risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem possibly, because I don't have Cygwin or a system to run Cygwin. I would try to replace the code above by

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::vector<T> makeVector(T (&array)[N]) {
    return std::vector<T>(array, array + N);
}
```

... and see if the problem persists. BTW, the code referenced in the comment compiles  for me (well, I needed to remove the include guards which are not needed in source files and only in headers).

Comment: Actually you are right with names starting with underscore. If I changed it to classic name like 'N' it works.
I found _N defined like 04 in ctype.h which is included to source code by cctype.h . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CdTCzech: You can use the `-E` option of the compiler to find out how the code looks after preprocessing. In the code you posted on pastebin I also noticed names with two underscores: any name including two underscores (anywhere) is also reserved.

Comment: Very useful information - thanks again. I found it in .o file.
And I promise that I will avoid names with an underscore in my codes.

Answer (score 1):

I found that _N cannot be used by us in cygwin because _N seems to already be defined as a numeric constant. Just replace *N by other names such as N*.